# Hive- how do I "create table as select.." with partitions from original table?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, create-table

I need to create a "work table" from our hive dlk. While I can use:

```
create table my_table as
select *
from dlk.big_table
```

just fine, I have problem with carrying over partitions (attributes `day`, `month` and `year`) from original "big_table" or just creating new ones from these attributes.
Searching the web did not really helped me answer this question- all "tutorials" or solutions deal either with `create as select` OR creating partitions, never both.
Can anybody here please help?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Creating partitioned table as select is not supported. You can do it in two steps:

1. `create table my_table like dlk.big_table;`
   This will create table with the same schema.
2. Load data.

   `set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
   set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;`

   `insert overwrite table my_table partition (day, month, year) 
   select * from dlk.big_table;`

Comment: It work perfectly, thank you. Btw, If I wanted to select only some of the columns from 'big_table' and add some new ones as regex extracts from them, can I do it in one command, or is it more practical just to do it with 'alter add', 'insert overwrite' and 'drop' commands?

Comment: @MageInTraining Then create table with necessary columns `create table (column list)` and use insert select columns calculated. Maybe I do not understand completely what are you are asking. Better ask this as a question and provide detailed description, someone else may help with it.

Comment: I will try to tinker around with this first. Thank you once again.