# Pyspark sql to create hive partitioned table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I am trying to create a hive paritioned table from pyspark dataframe using spark sql. Below is the command I am executing, but getting an error. Error message below.

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView(df_view)
spark.sql("create table if not exists tablename PARTITION (date) AS select * from df_view")
```

Error: `pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException:u"\nmismatched input 'PARTITION' expecting <EOF>`

When I try to run without PARTITION (date) in the above line it works fine. However I am unable to create with partition.

How to create table with partition and insert date from.pyspark dataframe to hive.

Comment: I can't test it, but [CTAS with partitioning looks to be not supported by Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56000714/hive-how-do-i-create-table-as-select-with-partitions-from-original-table)

Comment: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/2.x/spark-sql/language-manual/create-table.html    Partitioned by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address this I created the table first

spark.sql("create table if not exists table_name (name STRING,age INT) partitioned by (date_column STRING)")

Then set dynamic partition to nonstrict using below.
spark.sql("SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true")
spark.sql("SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict")
spark.sql("insert into table table_name PARTITION (date_column) select *,'%s from df_view" % current_date))

Where current date is a variable with today's date.

Comment: There u go.....